# Docker quickstart terminal error pull image

Tags: docker

I tried to install docker into my "Windows 10 family v.1803". I successfully manage to install docker toolbox and launch the "Docker Quickstart Terminal".

However, when typing `docker pull hello-word`, I got the following error:

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hello-word, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

I tried to log in and launching the command again but the error stay the same.

When I type `docker version`, I got this:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      18.09.0
  API version:  1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.4
  Git commit:   4d60db4
  Built:        Wed Nov  7 00:52:55 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

When I type `docker info`, I got that:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.79-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.0 (TCL 8.2.1)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 989.4MiB
Name: default
ID: I5OA:ASSA:S3VN:NELD:R5DN:UTLN:WXCG:PAN7:PDAW:AS5G:WM4B:IKDF
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: nolwenn
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

---

Since I already had an ubuntu shell install in my windows, I also tried to install docker there (which worked, almost) but got the following error:

```
$ sudo docker pull hello-word
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

---

Any idea on how I could solve this (apart from "install a Windows Pro/Linux")?

I already checked [here](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/#configure-http-proxy-settings-on-docker-machines) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a real problem or a typo but the image which you have used is not correct. `hello-word` doesn't look like a public dockerhub image.

Fetch it using `hello-world` not `hello-word` -

`$ docker pull hello-world`

Comment: happens with everyone ;)